# How to use vmImage on pipeline using Azure DevOps Server?

Tags: azure-devops, agent, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-server

Following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), I am trying to use `vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'` in Azure Devops Server.

How can I use `vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'` in my Azure DevPps Server?

Answer (score 3):

We **can't** use `ubuntu-latest` in Azure DevOps Server.

Those VmImages are only for [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and Microsoft-hosted agents are only for Azure Devops **Service**.

Please check the statement from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=yaml):

> Microsoft-hosted agents are only available with Azure DevOps Services,
> which is hosted in the cloud. **You cannot use** Microsoft-hosted agents
> or the Azure Pipelines agent pool **with on-premises TFS or Azure DevOps**
> Server. With these on-premises versions, you must use self-hosted
> agents.

Since you're using the Azure Devops Server, you should install the [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=browser#install). About how to choose specific agent in self-hosted agent pool, you can check [demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manually-entered-demands) syntax for more details.